# How to view autogenerated code in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, grid, telerik

I'm using Telerik's Grid control and it's seemingly randomly throwing an exception: a key is  being added twice to a dictionary in some auto generated code. Is there a way I can view this auto generated code so I can get a better understanding of what's happening?

Comment: We need more code, please show how you are calling telerik

Comment: Yep, some code goodies would be useful to give an answer

Answer (score 0):

Their MVC controls are open source http://telerikaspnetmvc.codeplex.com/. Include their projects in your solution, hit CTRL+ALT+E and select Break on All Exceptions. That should get you to the code you are looking for.